# Hotspot history

Tags: logs, access-point

I set up a wireless access point with my Linux machine. Now I want to know if a device accessed the Wi-Fi Hotspot and for how long. Is there any log file where I can find that information?

I already tried to get the information out of the `syslog` file. But this is also full of other information I am not interested in. Is there anything better I can work with?

The OS I am using is Raspbian Strech Lite on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: kindly confirm a point is it a GUI or ssh access ? and if so kindly try with `sudo less /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* `

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη There is no `NetworkManager` folder. I forgot to say that I am using Raspbian Strech Lite on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: that's make sense now, how about installing network manager in your OS in order to detect the incoming traffic for your access point ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Is there a good lightweight network manager for Raspbian?

Comment: try with `wicd`